# How to use SQL Parameter in this situation

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

My query is this:
`"SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()"`

But I want to use a SQL Parameter so it could be something like this:
`"SELECT TOP @ParameterName * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()"`

The normal way dosen't work:

```
Ct.Command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP @ParameterName * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()"
Ct.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", SomeValue)
```

How can I add a Parameter in this situation?

Comment: Not sure but you could try with `SELECT TOP (@ParameterName) * FROM ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply put parenthesis around the parameter. Supported since SQL Server 2005

```
Ct.Command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (@ParameterName) * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()"
```

Note: [TOP *without* parenthesis](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx) is for backwards compatibility; they should always be used

> For backward compatibility, TOP expression without parentheses in SELECT statements is supported, but we do not recommend this.

Comment: Its interesting that the microsoft site says parentheses should always be used but when you right click a table and select top 1000 in management studio, the autogenerated query has no parentheses

Comment: @Manatherin: doesn't surprise me at all :-) Different teams probably

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use the parameter this way?  May be you will do something like this:

```
Ct.Command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP {0} * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic T-SQL

```
EXEC('SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@ParameterName AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()')
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Marc_s. Just a question, did you mark the answer as not useful? because I believe the usefulness of an answer does not depend on stylish, so if you can explain why this answer is not useful will be helpful.

Comment: It's not wrong - but I would always avoid dynamic SQL unless you absolutely have to. A `TOP` clause can be easily parametrized - there's absolutely no need for dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Agree with @marc_s, there is no need for dynamic SQL at all. This code fails anyway because it uses double quotes and concatenates in the EXEC itself. So it's both wrong and not needed...

Answer (score -1):

You have to create dynamic SQL here.

```
Ct.Command.CommandText = 
    String.Format("SELECT TOP {0} * FROM [TableName] ORDER By NEWID()",SomeValue)
```